# MVC: Post array of values to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC website.  One of the pages allows the user to dynamically add drop down lists to the page, i.e. the user enters 5, this posts back to the server, where in the view I create 5 drop down lists.

What I then want to be able todo is on every post back **send all the values of the drop down lists back to the controller, maintaing their position in the array**.  What I'm finding is that only the changed values are being posted back and I am unable to determine which value changed

?? What, you may ask.  Here's an example:

1. The page allows the user to enter a
   specification of their house.  First
   they select from a drop down list,
   drpRooms, the number of rooms in
   their house (lets say the users
   enters 5).
2. This posts back to server and the
   view is rendered back with 5 additional drop
   down lists, drpRoom0, drpRoom1,
   drpRoom2 ... drpRoom4, each drop
   down lists allow them to select the
   number of items of furiture in that
   room, a number between 1 and 10.
3. The user selects the following
   values for each drop down

   drpRoom0: 2
   drpRoom1: 4
   drpRoom2: 1
   drpRoom3: 8
   drpRoom4: 9
4. When the user clicks "Continue" and
   posts the form back, I get the values in the
   controller as an array, i.e.. an Array of type
   int : int[] with values {2, 4, 1, 8,
   9}. Upto here I'm okay, I can get the drop down lists posted back as an array of int (I do this by using the same name for each drop down list, but unique ID's)
5. This will do some processing and so
   forth. The view gets rendered back
   to the user and they can change a
   value, say they change the value of
   drpRoom3 to value 2, when the user
   clicks continue, all I get back at
   the server is an array with 1 value
   at index 0.  Thus I'm unable to
   determine which drop down list was
   changed.

I know I can do this with Json, however I'm looking for Javascript independant way in which todo this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the MVC SelectList object in order to generate your DropDownList controls, and use the Model/ViewModel pattern in order to persist the changes in your system.

First, create the ViewModel class that will used to pass the data to the view:

```
public class RoomDetailsViewModel
{
    private int _numberOfRooms;
    public int NumberOfRooms
    {
        get { return _numberOfRooms; }
        set
        {
            _numberOfRooms = value;

            RoomDetails = new List<SelectList>(_numberOfRooms);
            for(int i = 0; i < _numberOfRooms; i++)
                RoomDetails.Add(new SelectList(AllowedRoomValues));
        }
    }
    public List<SelectList> RoomDetails { get; set; }

    public RoomDetailsViewModel(RoomDetailsModel model)
    {
        // Get useful info from dataModel
        NumberOfRooms = model.NumberOfRooms;
    }

    public static int[] AllowedRoomValues = new [] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10};
}
```

Note the use of a List of SelectList. Those will be used to generate the DropDownList you need. You can limit the options of your SelectList by providing a list of values (see *AllowedRoomValues*).

Next, in the Edit view, use the Html helper in order to generate the drop down lists:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="NumberOfRooms">NumberOfRooms:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("NumberOfRooms", Model.NumberOfRooms) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("NumberOfRooms", "*") %>
        </p>

        <% for(int i = 0; i < Model.NumberOfRooms; i++)
           { %>
                <%= Html.DropDownList("drpRoom" + i,Model.RoomDetails[i]) %>
        <% } %>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

As you can see you have to make sure the RoomDetails property is never null or you will throw a NullRef exception. Best way to do this is via the constructor and setters and I did in the ViewModel.

Finally, you need to update your model in the POST Edit action of your controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    // Grab the actual data model from your ORM repository of choice here
    RoomDetailsModel dataModel = roomDetailRepository.GetItem(r => r.HouseID == id);

    try
    {
        // Updating the model/
        for (int i = 0; i < model.NumberOfRooms; i++) // iterate over actual room count
            dataModel.RoomDetails[i] = int.Parse(collection["drpRoom" + i]);

        // Generate a ViewModel from your actual DataModel in order to display.
        RoomDetailsViewModel viewModel = new RoomDetailsViewModel(dataModel);

        // display back the view using the viewModel.
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    catch
    {
        // error handling...
        return View();
    }
}
```

I omitted all data validation stuff for brievity, you get the idea! OTH!